# How to show/hide divs based on a dropdown box selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide, dropdown

I know I'm not the only person with this problem, but I couldn't find a javascript solution yet.

This is my dropdown selection. Now I want to display a specific message for each option.

```
<select name="lehrberuf" id="lehrberuf" class="browser-default" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected class="grey-text">Lehrberuf</option>
    <option value="Anlagenfuehrer/-in EFZ">Anlagenführer/-in EFZ</option>
    <option value="Anlagen- und Apparatebauer/-in EFZ">Anlagen- und Apparatebauer/-in EFZ</option>
    <option value="Automatiker/-in EFZ">Automatiker/-in EFZ</option>
    <option value="Elektroinstallateur/-in EFZ">Elektroinstallateur/-in EFZ</option>
    <option value="Elektroplaner/-in EFZ">Elektroplaner/-in EFZ</option>
    <option value="Fachmann/-frau Betriebsunterhalt EFZ">Fachmann/-frau Betriebsunterhalt EFZ</option>
    <option value="Informatiker/-in EFZ">Informatiker/-in EFZ</option>
    <option value="Kauffrau / Kaufmann EFZ">Kauffrau / Kaufmann EFZ</option>
    <option value="Konstrukteur/-in EFZ">Konstrukteur/-in EFZ</option>
    <option value="Kunststofftechnologe/-technologin EFZ">Kunststofftechnologe/-technologin EFZ</option>
    <option value="Laborant/-in EFZ Fachrichtung Chemie">Laborant/-in EFZ Fachrichtung Chemie</option>
    <option value="Logistiker/-in EFZ Fachrichtung Lager">Logistiker/-in EFZ Fachrichtung Lager</option>
    <option value="Mediamatiker/-in EFZ">Mediamatiker/-in EFZ</option>
    <option value="Polymechaniker/-in EFZ">Polymechaniker/-in EFZ</option>
</select>
```

This should be the message for each option.

```
<div class="row col s12">
    <div class="hiddenmessage1">You have to select <strong>any one option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="hiddenmessage2">You have selected <strong>red option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="hiddenmessage3">You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="hiddenmessage4">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="hiddenmessage5">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="hiddenmessage6">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="hiddenmessage7">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="hiddenmessage8">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="hiddenmessage9">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="hiddenmessage10">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="hiddenmessage11">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="hiddenmessage12">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="hiddenmessage13">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="hiddenmessage14">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
</div>
```

I need some help with the JS.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please note that are not a code writing service, please add the code you've written yourself to solve this issue to the question. Secondly, you've not shown how the second block of HTML is in any way related to the first, or what behaviour you're expecting under which events.

Comment: From next time please try to post your code also. For now check this http://jsfiddle.net/9ch2wuvp/

Comment: sry i'm new here and i'm very bad at developing :/ thank you for the solution! Next time i'll try to upload my code to a jsfiddle as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#lehrberuf').on('change',function(){
        var getIndex = $(this).find('>option:selected').index();
        $('.row > div').hide(); // you can use slideDown() or fadeOut() instead of .hide()
        $('.row > div').eq(getIndex).show(); // you can use slideUp() or fadeIn() instead of .hide()
    });
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/8rtbdxha/2/)

Comment: @digb you welcome .. but please be sure to include jquery to let this code work .. Good Luck :)

Comment: I like how this is very succinct, and great use of selectors, my only criticism would be it relies completely on the divs being in the same order as the dropdown options.

Comment: @Shaun nice name .. cause I like Shaun Murphy is one from my best snooker player ever :) .. I worked for what the OP asked for .. so its like an exam try to solve it? or trying to re-structure it? :) ..  This what Stackoverflow is .. everyone has his own code and you just trying to help

Comment: Ha I'll have to look him up! Absolutely. I like the answer was just a comment really, and only commented because it was otherwise a great answer, shows the power of jQuery. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 $('#lehrberuf ').on('change',function(){
   var index = $('#lehrberuf option').index($(this).find(':selected'));
 console.log(index);
   $('.hiddenmessage'+(index+1)).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's awful coding practice to have so many divs if you can avoid it. Imagine you need to change the layout or other changes, you have to do it 10+ times or change 10+ class definitions.

Your drop down only has a single selection, so why not just have one div, and replace the content?

You have html such as:

```
<select onchange="showText(this)">
   <option value="my text">text</option>
<select>

<div id="dvContent">select an option!</div>
```

Then javascript :

```
<script>
  function showText(dd) {
     var sel = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].value,
     dv = document.getElementById("dvContent");
     dv.innerHTML = sel.value;
  }
 </script>
```

Please do have a go next time, you won't learn by others coding for you. The only way to learn is make mistakes.

This doesn't use *jQuery*, personally I think it's best to learn properly then use *jQuery* for convenience. But this could be minimised a little with *jQuery* if you prefer.

Comment: sry i'm new here and i'm very bad at developing :/ thank you for the solution! Next time i'll try to upload my code to a jsfiddle as well!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#lehrberuf').change(function() {

    var selected_index = $('#lehrberuf option:selected').index();
var text_in_div = $('#messages > div:eq('+selected_index+')').text();
alert(text_in_div);

});​
```